# Centos 6: не прописывается Gateway

Tags: windows, squid, centos

Сервер centos 6 используется как шлюз в локалке из нескольких Windows машин. На нем настроен squid и все компьютеры сети выходят в инет через этот сервер. Но меня настораживает, что route -n показывает:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  XX.XX.XXX.X     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0  192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2  XXX.XXX.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1  XXX.XXX.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
```

Возможно из-за этого у меня проблемы с получением/отправкой почты. Я в конфиги сети добавил GATEWAY="ИП полученный от провайдера":

```
/etc/sysconfig/network:  NETWORKING=yes  NETWORKING_IPV6=no  HOSTNAME=mydomain  FORWARD_IPV4=yes  GATEWAY=XX.XX.XXX.XXX  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1 (смотрит в инет):  DEVICE=em1  HWADDR=хх:хх:хх:хх:хх:хх  NM_CONTROLLED=no  ONBOOT=yes  BOOTPROTO=static  GATEWAY=XX.XX.XXX.XXX  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts//ifcfg-ppp0 (PPP0E на сетевой em1)  USERCTL=yes  BOOTPROTO=dialup  NAME=DSLppp0  DEVICE=ppp0  TYPE=xDSL  ONBOOT=yes  PIDFILE=/var/run/pppoe-adsl.pid  FIREWALL=MASQUERADE  PING=.  PPPOE_TIMEOUT=80  LCP_FAILURE=3  LCP_INTERVAL=20  CLAMPMSS=1412  CONNECT_POLL=6  CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60  DEFROUTE=yes  SYNCHRONOUS=no  ETH=em1  PROVIDER=DSLppp0   USER=Имя, полученный от провайдера  PEERDNS=no  DEMAND=no  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em2 (карточка смотрит в локалку):  DEVICE=em2  NM_CONTROLLED=no  ONBOOT=yes  BOOTPROTO=static  IPV6INIT=no  NAME="System em2"  UUID=0578038a-64e9-a2fd-0a28-e4cd0b553930  HWADDR=78:2B:CB:53:EF:41  IPADDR=192.168.1.1  NETMASK=255.255.255.0  NETWORK=192.168.1.0  TYPE=Ethernet  GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Но это не помогло. В чем нужно разбираться?

Answer (score 1):

```
NAME="System em2"UUID=0578038a-64e9-a2fd-0a28-e4cd0b553930HWADDR=78:2B:CB:53:EF:41IPADDR=192.168.1.1NETMASK=255.255.255.0NETWORK=192.168.1.0TYPE=EthernetGATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

т.е. он сам для себя является гатавеем? как-то странно.

**//upd**

```
 XX.XX.XXX.X 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 ppp0    192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 em2    XXX.XXX.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1002 0 0 em1    XXX.XXX.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1003 0 0 em2    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 U 0 0 0 ppp0
```

А почему нули стоят везде. да еще и в конце через точку между ними? поставь вместо них *

Это точно конфиг сквида? как-то странно выглядит.

Comment: Если бы не ppp0e, я бы присвоил em1 IP, полученный от провайдера и в настройках em2 в качестве GW указал бы этот адрес. А сейчас я не совсем уверен, как все это должно быть.

Comment: "почему нули стоят везде. да еще и в конце через точку между ними? поставь вместо них *"((( Если бы я знал, почему это происходит, я бы не создал этот пост. Я и хочу разобраться, как сделать, чтобы здесь все было нормально.

Answer (score 0):

shrek прав и из-за того что вы навешали ip адреса судя по "System em2" на всех остальных такая же ситуация, у вас 2 канала на внешку и вы хотите сделать балансировку?

Comment: Нет, канал на внешку 1 - через em1, доступ по ppp0E. И я так понимаю, что в настройках em2 должно быть GW=ИП провайдера?

Comment: Если у вас компьютеры в первой подсети на em2 то присвойте ей любой адрес но не 192.168.1.1, и для PPPoE не всегда требуется ip адрес присваивать на сетевую карту, вообще для полной картины желательно описать сетевую карту чтобы понять что вы хотите получить (для чего вы PPPoE используете?)

Comment: Сетевая карта em1: к ней подключен кабель от провайдера.  Сетевая карта em2: к ней подключен коммутатор (к которому подключены windows машины).  Тип протокола подключения провайдера PPP0E.  Исходя из всего этого я и настраивал сеть. Если как-то по другому нужно все делать, дайте, пожалуйста ссылку, где можно посмотреть. Хотя я долго гуглил, но не нашел подходящее к моей ситуации.

Comment: "Если у вас компьютеры в первой подсети на em2 то присвойте ей любой адрес но не 192.168.1.1, и для PPPoE не всегда требуется ip адрес присваивать на сетевую карту".  А почему нельзя присвоить 192.168.1.1 карте em2?  PPP0E - со статическим адресом, поэтому я решил его прописать.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь. [CentOS 5: Настройка интернет-шлюза с DHCP-сервером.](http://metalcandy.ru/how-to-forge-centos/371-centos-5-configure-the-gateway-with-dhcp-server)

Comment: Попробовал так тоже. Но без DHCP - у меня всего 5 рабочих станций, я прописал уже вручную ИП. Но при таких настройках, как указано там, у меня пропадает интерфейс ppp0 и нет доступа к интернет, хотя в локалке все работает.

Comment: Сбрось все настройки iptables  опцией -F и перенастрой заново

Comment: Не помогло.